# DocuSign - how to redirect from iframe to the app AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, docusignapi

I want to make a redirection from the `iframe` of DocuSign (when I finish the state treatment) to my application AngularJS

My page is like this:

```
<div data-ng-controller="myController">
  <iframe id="iframeID" ng-src="{{url}}"></iframe>
</div>
```

How can I exit from the iframe and enter inside my app AngularJS?

Comment: <div data-ng-controller="controller">
 <iframe id="iframeID" ng-src="{{url}}" ></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>$window or $location to Redirect URL in AngularJS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('RedirectURLApp', []);
    app.controller('RedirectURLCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
      $scope.name = 'Anil';
      $scope.RedirectToURL = function() {
        var host = $window.location.host;
        var landingUrl = "http://www.google.com";
        alert(landingUrl);
        $window.location.href = landingUrl;
      };
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="RedirectURLApp">
  <div ng-controller="RedirectURLCtrl">
    <h2>$window or $location to Redirect URL in AngularJS</h2>
    <p>Hello {{name}},</p>
    Click to Redirect <a href="#" ng-click="RedirectToURL()">Click Me!</a>
  </div>
  <div><h4><a href="http://www.code-sample.com/2015/06/redirect-to-new-page-using-location-or.html">For more detail..</a></h4></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nava, But the problem is an Iframe generated by the API DocuSign,
i can't add a controller. Also, when i finish the signature an DocuSign, The Api will create a new  <html><body>. 
So , i can't control my page.

Answer (score 0):

Why use an iFrame? Instead, redirect the user's browser to DocuSign for the signing ceremony, then DocuSign will redirect back to your angular app after the person has signed.

True, your Angular app will be restarted, but all of its assets should be cached by the browser. You can tell DocuSign what url to redirect to, so your Angular app can recover its state, know that it was started as a result of a signing ceremony, etc.